# Spell check software tool for ERP application and website

Tags: manual-testing, gui, uiautomation

Currently am checking the website, In the website I need to check spelling errors and broken links, Is there is any software tool to do this task.

Also can able to test spelling error in any product software like ERP applications?

Let me know your thoughts.

Comment: The software is web based? And can you elaborate on why this is tagged with both automation and manual-testing?

Comment: Yes web based..

Answer (score 1):

You can use W3C's link checker for broken links:

- https://validator.w3.org/checklink

And typosaurus for spell checking websites. This is also available as a Chrome extension, but I haven't used it myself so can't vouch for it:

- http://typosaur.us/

Both of these are free to use, but I believe typosaurus can only spell check English... hopefully that's what you're after?

Thanks,
Dan